# Time-varying edge cost Minimum Spaning Tree

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, greedy-algorithms, minimum-spanning-tree

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the time-varying edge cost of this question :

> Suppose we have a connected graph $G = (V, E)$. Each edge e now has a time-varying edge cost given by a function $f_e$. Thus, at time t, it has cost
> $f_e(t)$. We’ll assume that all these functions are positive over their entire
> range. Observe that the set of edges constituting the minimum spanning
> tree of $G$ may change over time. Also, of course, the cost of the minimum
> spanning tree of $G$ becomes a function of the time $t$; we’ll denote this
> function $c_G(t)$. A natural problem then becomes: find a value of $t$ at which
> $c_G(t)$ is minimized.
> Suppose each function $f_e$ is a polynomial of degree 2: $f_e(t) = a_et^2 + b_et + c_e$ , where $a_e$ is positive for each edge $e$. Give an algorithm that takes the graph $G$ and the
> values $\{(a_e , b_e , c_e) : e ∈ E\}$ and returns a value of the time $t$ at which the
> minimum spanning tree has minimum cost. Your algorithm should run
> in time polynomial in the number of nodes and edges of the graph $G$. You
> may assume that arithmetic operations on the numbers $\{(a_e , b_e , c_e)\}$ can
> be done in constant time per operation.

My first idea was, because $a_e$ is positive, to find out the maximum value of $t$ that minimizes the cost of an edge $e$ (in other words looping through every edge once and find their minima). Intuitively, the maximum of these minima could be an upper-bound for the value that minimizes $c_G(t)$. Then I could run a MST algorithm for every time step from 0 to t and return the t that answers the question.
However, this looks like a very brute-forcey method and thus not time-efficient at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note that this question was part of the [Greedy Algorithm chapter](https://www.cs.sjtu.edu.cn/%7Ejiangli/teaching/CS222/files/materials/Algorithm%20Design.pdf).

Comment: We require you to attribute the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Saying it came from "the Greedy Algorithm chapter" is not adequate.  Please see the link for our expectations about providing a proper reference: e.g., we'd expect you to provide a full reference, including the textbook name and authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the edges sorted by $f_e(t)$ for some $t$.

Two quadratic polynomials can intersect at most two times.  When the cost function of two edges $e_1$ and $e_2$ cross at time $t$, it means that

- $f_{e_1}(t-\epsilon) < f_{e_2}(t-\epsilon)$ and
- $f_{e_1}(t+\epsilon) > f_{e_2}(t+\epsilon)$.

Since there are $m$ edges and each pair of edges crosses at most twice, we have at most $2 \cdot {m \choose 2} \leq m^2$ many crossings, and therefore at most $m^2$ many times two edges can swap order in the sorted list.

Now you try all possible time intervals that don't contain crossings, $(t_a, t_b)$ and pick the $n-1$ cheapest edges.  What remains is to minimize a sum over $n-1$ quadratic functions which is indeed a quadratic function.